# Dependent dropdowns or similar, using mootools, php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mootools

I need to find some way of displaying a drop-down menu that depending on what is chosen will display a second tier of results in another drop-down. All data will be stored in database. Any other similar techniques are welcome. I am currently using mootools, with php and Mysql.

Any help or thoughts welcome on this one...

Comment: PHP and MySQL are irrelevant unless you're looking to use AJAX instead of preload. Are you?

Comment: I need to call the values from the database, this is why I mentioned them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic outline of what you need to do:

Attach an `onChange` event to your `<select>` control

In the event handler, make a request to a php file (using [mootools Request object](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request)). Pass the selected value from the form control.

In the php file, grab the form value out of `$_POST` and do whatever query you need to get the result set.

If you used Request.HTML, you can build a string that will be inserted into an element when the request finishes. I haven't had much luck using this to build out `<select>` controls. I'd probably use Request.JSON, and use the `onSuccess` property of your Request.JSON object to build out the new select control.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is ready this wondering the same, I did find this: [Chained Select](http://www.php-help.ro/php-tutorials/javascript-chained-select-with-mootools-12/) Which has done the job for me...